# react native(IOS). I need to update and print value latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, react-native

I need to update latitude and longitude from real location (current location not fake location that I set)

the value that I set is fake location
latitude: 14.0208,
Longitude: 100.525

and I try to release on my device. GPS is working

but I don't know how to print from real location(update realtime)

thank you.

this is my code:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    Dimensions,
    TouchableOpacity,
    MapView
} from 'react-native';
var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
import api from './api';
import Profile from './Profile';
import ScrollableTabView, {DefaultTabBar, ScrollableTabBar } from 'react-native-scrollable-tab-view';
import Info from './Info';
// import motion from './motion';





export default class Route extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        region: {
            latitude: 14.0208,
            longitude: 100.5250,
        }
    };

}




    render() {
        return (


            <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollableTabView
            style={{marginTop: 20, }}
            initialPage={2}
            renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTabBar />}
        >
            <Text tabLabel='Profile'></Text>
            <Text tabLabel='Route'></Text>
            <Text tabLabel='Information'></Text>
            </ScrollableTabView>
            <TouchableOpacity tabLabel='Profile' onPress={() => this.tabView.Profile(2)}>
         </TouchableOpacity>

        <MapView style={styles.map}
          mapType="standard"
          showsUserLocation={true}
          followsUserLocation={true}
          showsCompass={false}
          showsPointOfInterest={false}
                    region={this.state.region}
          onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
        >

        </MapView>
                <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>
          Latitude: {this.state.region.latitude}{'\n'}
          Longitude: {this.state.region.longitude}{'\n'}

          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>

        );
    }
}





const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'white'
    },
    image: {
        width: 200,
        height: 180,
    },
    text: {
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        marginTop: 20,
    },
    map: {
        //top: -150,
    width: 700,
    height: 400
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually listen to the GPS and update using its data. Look at this documentation, particularly "watchPosition". You can set the callback of watchPosition to a setter in your component that sets state.region.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html

Comment: I can solve it but when I reload it just slower on simulator (delay) how to solve this problem 

I just add on my code and got delay

this.onRegionChange = this.onRegionChange.bind(this);
}

onRegionChange(region) {
 this.setState({ region });
}